# Worklight Unified Push Notification - JMS Queue Pulling Architecture

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

For reference check the below URL.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/worklight_push_notification_possible_architectures?lang=en

I have hosted my Worklight Server in IBM softlayer. Is SoftLayer Message Queue is a JMS 2.0 API based message queue or different. If its a JMS based message queue, it possible to use that for IBM Worklight Unified Push Notification.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question if you are asking whether this is possible, or that you have done so and ask for opinions...  Edit the question and clarify.

If the SoftLayer Message Queue supports JMS, then it will probably work.
If not, then you should probably go for the second architecture from the linked blog post.

Answer (score 0):

SO a few clarification here:
1 Of this is hosted on SoftLayer --- can u add more details... SL has may products include typical IaaS type offerings and services and API include Message queuing an Object storage.
2. Softlayer also provides server/storage/network etc which are IaaS type offerings.

assuming you installed WL on a instance and has access to SL networks etc to the other services hosted on SL, if connectivity exists and you can create JMS adapters, this seems possible.

Now:
1. The IBM Worklight JMS adapter can be used to send and receive messages from a JMS-enabled messaging provider. It can be used to send and receive the headers and body of the messages.
2. To start receiving push notifications, an application must first subscribe to a push notification event source. The event source is a push notification channel to which mobile applications can register. An event source is defined within a Worklight adapter. The device user must approve the push notification subscription. 
so technically you should be able to use JMS compliant message queue as an even source.

N

Comment: Hi, Edited my question for better understanding.